# Forward port to address

Tags: domain-name-system, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to figure out how to map a specific address on a port on a different address. This might be very trivial, but I am not even sure how to ask Google.

I have one machine running two servers: one on port 443, one on port 10000, and one on port 4567. They are all using SSL. My machine has the IP address 123.456.789.123, and so I mapped my domain name `www.machine.com` to it, and forward the ports in the router, so that I can access the three servers as follows, resp.:

- https:// www.machine.com
- https:// www.machine.com:10000
- https:// www.machine.com:4567

How could I modify my settings to instead have

- https:// www.machine.com
- https:// server.machine.com
- https:// other.machine.com

? Would changes have to occur on my DNS provider, on my router, or on my machine?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done using DNS directly. A domain name always resolves to a single IP address, the port isn't related to DNS records at all.

However, you can set up a **reverse proxy** on your web server that is listening on port 443.

You would set up virtual hosts `server.machine.com` and `other.machine.com` on the `www.machine.com` web server, which would then proxy the requests to the web servers on ports 10000 and 4567 respectively.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server

Comment: Thank you so much. Keyword was reverse proxy, definitely.